# Почему не получается открыть текстовый файл при помощи Python

Tags: python, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не получается открыть текстовый файл при помощи Python, хотя этот файл находится в одной директории с .py файлом

Comment: Потому что ищется не там, где находится, а там, где запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл ищется в текущем каталоге, то есть в каталоге, из которого был запущен скрипт.
Таким каталогом в Вашем случае является `C:/Users/Irbis`.

Так как в текущем каталоге нет файла `words.txt`, Вы получаете ошибку.

---

Для того чтобы исправить это, Вы можете:

- Изменить текущий каталог

  *В консоли:*

  ```
  cd Irbis/Desktop/Python
  ```
- Указать абсолютный путь

  ```py
  open('C:/Users/Irbis/Desktop/Python/words.txt')
  ```
- Указать путь относительно текущего каталога

  ```py
  open('Desktop/Python/words.txt')
  ```
- Изменить текущий каталог средствами `Python`

  ```py
  import os


  os.chdir('C:/Users/Irbis/Desktop/Python')
  open('words.txt')
  ```